# "No message found under code" if class is not in base-package of servlet-context. Why?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, internationalization

It is the part of servlet-context relating to internalisation.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.project.controllers" />

<interceptors>
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
        p:paramName="lang" />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor" />
</interceptors>

<!-- i18n -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
    id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages, WEB-INF/i18n/application"
    p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
    id="localResolver" p:cookieName="locale" />
```

The root-context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.project"/>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

If I try to get message within jsp page or within controllers package everything is ok:

```
messageSource.getMessage("message.code", new Object[] {}, locale)
```

But it does not work out of the package defined in servlet-context, though messageSource bean is autowired.

Does it mean that root-context has default messageSource and in servlet-context it is overriden only for particular package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration defined in ServletContext for a specific controller always overrides the configuration of the rootContext. Also it is private to the root context.

The configuration you put in the servlet context is specific to that particular servlet/controller. If you need a global functionality for internationalization you should define the messageSource bean in the root Context.

When an ApplicationContext is loaded, it automatically searches for a MessageSource bean defined in the context. The bean must have the name messageSource. If such a bean is found, all calls to the preceding methods are delegated to the message source. If no message source is found, the ApplicationContext attempts to find a parent containing a bean with the same name. If it does, it uses that bean as the MessageSource. **If the ApplicationContext cannot find any source for messages, an empty DelegatingMessageSource is instantiated in order to be able to accept calls to the methods defined above.**

Comment: Is it mean that root-context has default messageSource? I do not define it there, but it is autowired.

Comment: The ApplicationContext interface extends an interface called MessageSource, and therefore provides internationalization (i18n) functionality. Spring also provides the interface HierarchicalMessageSource, which can resolve messages hierarchically. Together these interfaces provide the foundation upon which Spring effects message resolution http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s13.html

yes it picks up the default message source